# How to list a series of related experiences in CV

Tags: cv

## Problem

I am applying for Ph.D. in electrical engineering. Since the first few deadlines are coming, I am making final revisions to my CV.

There are two related questions

1. I have a rather long (about 15 months) research experience that yield several preprints and a thesis. Is it fine to list all of them under one entry (see below). The issue is that the items (a, b, c...) become too many (8 in my case). 
   Or maybe I need to split them base on milestones (based on preprints and thesis results).

> My Awesome Research Topic
>
> - a
> - b

2. I have taken two projects-based courses, where the professors talk about details about each particular algorithm and we need to do projects which use the algorithms. The same question re-emerges, do I split these experiences project by project or maybe organize under one common entry?
   If the latter is preferred, what should be the entry called, maybe something like "xxx Project Series"?

Appreciate any input.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is that the items (a, b, c...) become too many (8 in my case). Or maybe I need to split them base on milestones (based on preprints and thesis results).

Perhaps have a single list entry per publication. (Each list entry can highlight several points.)

> I have taken two projects-based courses, where the professors talk about details about each particular algorithm and we need to do projects which use the algorithms. The same question re-emerges, do I split these [two projects-based courses] project by project or maybe organize under one common entry? If the latter is preferred, what should be the entry called, maybe something like "xxx Project Series"?

You could list all the courses you've taken. (Under the title *201X-201Y, Degree classification, subject, university, country*, for instance.) You only need to discuss those with particular relevance, e.g., related to your PhD field. It seems unlikely that you'd need to discuss particular algorithms, unless they are in the field of your PhD and you are interested in pursuing them further.